# Extract Json elements from string

Tags: python, json

I'm getting data from an API as a python dict and appending it to a list, which is then dumped onto a txt file.

I am trying to read the huge string in the txt file and load into Json objects but am finding issues.

I take the dictionary and make it Json applicable, i.e.

```
jsonStr = json.dumps(d)
```

Where d is the dictionary returned by the API.

This `jsonStr` is then appended to a list.

As its a string, when put into a txt file the ' is still there../. e.g.

```
['{"md1": {"id": 422, "h": "bla"}}', '{"md2": {"id": 42211, "h": "bla2"}}']
```

I need to get rid of the `'` from each element. Can't figure out the best how to tackle this.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. If you're reading JSON, why are you using `json.dumps()` ? _I need to get rid of the `'` from each element._ It's probably a bad idea to think of it as simply removing a quotation mark.

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate on the other elements of the list? If the list contains no items that include single quotation marks, you can use `replace("'", "")` on the text in the file. This will replace all single quotation marks with nothing. A better way to do this, I believe, is to dump the JSON *after* it has been added to the list, like so:

```
the_list_to_which_you_append = [...]

the_list_to_which_you_append(d)
jsonStr = json.dumps(the_list_to_which_you_append)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

To convert a json into a string you do `json.dumps()`
To convert a string into a json you do `json.loads()`

So in your situation. Before you append it to a list you should convert the string to a json first. Then append it to the list. Then you can save your list to a textfile.